# Is there way to sort cases in list comprehension to produce two outputs?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm wondering if there is a way to write such a function with use of single list comprehension:

```
def sort_letters(word):
    lowers, uppers = [], []
    for letter in word:
            lowers.append(letter) if letter.islower() else uppers.append(letter)
    return lowers,uppers
```

I can write it like that:

```
def sort_letters2(word):
    return [x for x in word if x.islower()],[x for x in word if x.isupper()]
```

but it iterates twice through word. I'm curious how to sort letters within single list comprehension to get result similar to:

```
sort_letters("HaLLo")
(['a', 'o'], ['H', 'L', 'L'])
```

It doesn't necessary needs to look exactly like result up, but it should stick to idea of sorting lower case letters from upper. Is there way to write it like that?

Comment: List comprehension isn't there to write one-liners, its there to comprehend a list - use an if statement

Comment: Is there a particular reason why iterating twice through the list is bad?

Comment: If you want "a single list comprehension" you could do `[list(filter(f, word)) for f in (str.lower, str.upper)]`...

Comment: in your for loop `(lowers if letter.islower() else uppers).append(letter)`

Comment: @tobias_k but it is with two iteration

Comment: @splash58 Yes, but of all the versions so far this is IMHO the clearest. (Also works with more than two subsets, although that will be even more iterations.) Hence my question, why two iterations is so bad.

Comment: Not bad, but if source is huge, it really could get a long time. I like more @Chris_Rands approach